# express on alpine linux - creating express application fails

Tags: node.js, linux, express

I'm trying to create a node js application on alpine linux. 
I just did an

```
  apk add nodejs
```

And now I just tried this command:

```
myserver:/var/www/widgets# npm install express -g
express@4.14.0 /usr/lib/node_modules/express
├── escape-html@1.0.3
├── utils-merge@1.0.0
├── cookie-signature@1.0.6
├── merge-descriptors@1.0.1
├── methods@1.1.2
├── fresh@0.3.0
├── path-to-regexp@0.1.7
├── vary@1.1.0
├── encodeurl@1.0.1
├── range-parser@1.2.0
├── parseurl@1.3.1
├── array-flatten@1.1.1
├── etag@1.7.0
├── content-type@1.0.2
├── cookie@0.3.1
├── content-disposition@0.5.1
├── serve-static@1.11.1
├── depd@1.1.0
├── qs@6.2.0
├── on-finished@2.3.0 (ee-first@1.1.1)
├── finalhandler@0.5.0 (unpipe@1.0.0, statuses@1.3.0)
├── debug@2.2.0 (ms@0.7.1)
├── proxy-addr@1.1.2 (forwarded@0.1.0, ipaddr.js@1.1.1)
├── accepts@1.3.3 (negotiator@0.6.1, mime-types@2.1.12)
├── type-is@1.6.13 (media-typer@0.3.0, mime-types@2.1.12)
└── send@0.14.1 (destroy@1.0.4, ms@0.7.1, statuses@1.3.0, mime@1.3.4, http-errors@1.5.0)
```

But when i try to then create an express application, I'm getting an error.

```
 myserver:/var/www/widgets# express testapp
-ash: express: not found
 myserver:/var/www/widgets#
```

I'm not sure what I need to do next.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be that you want to install the `express-generator` module:

```
$ npm install express-generator -g
```

Once you've done this, you can then use:

```
$ express myapp
```

To generate your new application, where `myapp` is the name of the application.

Source: [Express application generator](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html)